# What's wrong with my incremental number program?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a program in which if variable *problem* is defined, add one to it. If not, create it and go back to the beginning. Yet when I run it, all I get is a list of zeroes. Why is this?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:start
if exist problem (set /a problem=%problem%+1) else (set problem=0)
echo %problem%
goto start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program have a couple details:

- The `enabledelayedexpansion` part is not required, because your program does not use a !variable! delayed expansion.
- `set /a` command does not require to expand variable values, so `set /a problem=problem+1` is enough; however, a simpler way to do the same is: `set /a problem+=1`.
- When `set /a` command try to operate a variable that is not defined, it automatically create it with zero value. This means that the entire `if defined ...` command is not required.

This way, your program could be as simple as:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:start
set /a problem+=1
echo %problem%
goto start
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using `if exist`, which is for testing if a directory or file exists. What you should be using in this case, when working with variables, is `if defined`.